# Angular V15 how to change style of active tab in mat-tab

Tags: angular

Angular V15 how to change style of active tab in mat-tab

I want to change style of active tab in mat-tab by define in scss:

```
.mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label-active{
 background-color: some-color
}
```

It was working on v14 but not in v15.

Comment: Hello @yafit and welcome to StackOverflow, as you are new here , it would be great if you make a check on our [Tour Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you can take an idea about how StackOverflow works.

Answer (score 2):

Mat-Tab is an external library that can be implemented in an encapsuled way, you can check [this link](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation) and [this link too](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) to understand how Angular works in a term of View Encapsulation & Styling.

In the past versions of Angular you may had to use `::ng-deep` preceded by `::host` selectors, *But this is actually DEPRECATED* and using it means you are implementing a *legacy code* according to [this long discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160).

Actually, I'm not sure about how you implemented your full code, but lets say that the structure of your View code is implemented that way below and you want to target `mat-tab-label-active` class:

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->
<mat-tab></mat-tab> 

<!-- lets say the previous line would generate the dom this way in the Browser: -->
<mat-tab>
  <element1 class="mat-tab-list">
     <element2 class="mat-tab-labels">
         <element3 class="mat-tab-label-active">
         </element3>
     </element2>
  </element1>
</mat-tab>
```

For that I would recommend to check [this official-like answer](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25160#issuecomment-504642697) and refactor your code this way:

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->
<mat-tab class="my-mat-tab"></mat-tab>
```

```css
/* app.component.css */
mat-tab.my-mat-tab .mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label-active{
 background-color: some-color
}
```

```
/** app.component.ts **/
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // <------ This is Important
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Quick Explication:

- In the typescript component level, we disabled the view encapsulation strategy by setting up : `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to make sure that our component styles are exposed to be customizable.
- However, making styles exposed globally/customizable would maybe impact other `mat-tab` styles in the same page that holds the same component. So to avoid that we setup a custom class to `mat-tab` to just only target it, exemple: `<mat-tab class="my-mat-tab">`.
- finally target the `mat-tab` container and its sub-elements in the css file by selecting the whole path of the target class.

**PS:** for now, there is no other alternatives in Angular docs neither in Angular Github discussions, but hopefully they can add something more clear and effecient to replace `::ng-deep` selector.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help, 
I need to use mat-tab-group, I tried your suggestion but it is not working, I adding encapsulation and declaring in css
.my-mat-tab .mdc-tab .mat-mdc-tab .mat-mdc-focus-indicator .mdc-tab-indicator--active{
    background-color: yellow;
}  
in my html:
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms" backgroundColor="accent" class="my-mat-tab">
    <mat-tab label="tab1" >
        content1
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="tab2">
         conent2
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
nothing happend
what do I do wrong?

Comment: @yafit I'm sorry because I could not help you with my answer above and it's weired that this did not work for you.. In this case, I would recommend you maybe to share your partial code in (at least the one where you implemented the mat-tab-group) on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) so we can help you by updating it directly ? It would be a great idea right ? ^_^